# Exception occurs when deserializing the following XML (from REST service), for no reason!

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, xml-serialization, deserialization

I am having trouble finding why the following XML won't deserialize.

Message:

> There is an error in XML document (23, 26).

Inner exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Calling Code (works without issue on everything except the XML below):

```
Public Shared Function DeserializeObject(Of T)(ByVal serializedXml As String) As T
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))

    Using strReader As New IO.StringReader(serializedXml)
        Return DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(strReader), T)
    End Using

End Function
```

XML (looks ok - issue is after the first open square bracket of DiscountCode):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyResponse>
    <Shoppinglist>
        <ShoppinglistName>ShoppingListName</ShoppinglistName>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <PriceType>Retail</PriceType>
        <Orders>
            <Order>
                <OrderLineId>Test</OrderLineId>
                <Completed>false</Completed>
                <Description>Other Item</Description>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <Parts>
                    <Part>
                        <PartId>43543543435</PartId>
                        <Description>Cylinder Assy - Master</Description>
                        <PriceInclTax>92.16</PriceInclTax>
                        <PriceExclTax>76.8</PriceExclTax>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <TaxRate>20.0</TaxRate>
                        <NetDiscountCode>ZZ</NetDiscountCode>
                        <SurchargeQuantity>1.0</SurchargeQuantity>
------------->          <DiscountRate>0.0</DiscountRate>
                    </Part>
                </Parts>
            </Order>
        </Orders>
    </Shoppinglist>
    <ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>
    <StatusMessage>Open tasks exist</StatusMessage>
</MyResponse>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Stack trace (for outer exception):

```
 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
```

Stack trace for inner exception:

```
 at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)    
 at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)    
 at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s)
```

Which is strange, as it looks like it is parsing to Int, when it should be parsing to decimal...

property for class T:

```
Protected _DiscountRate As Decimal
Public Property DiscountRate() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _DiscountRate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Decimal)
        _DiscountRate = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

I added the following, but it didn't make any difference:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Type:=GetType(Decimal))> _
```

I doubt this is to do with strange characters as I can't see any. Also changing the type to Double does not work around the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: My guess is that the field in `T` that receives the `DiscountRate` is an integral type, rather than a floating point type. It's impossible to tell for sure without being able to see the code for the class `T`.

Comment: DiscountRate is a Decimal type, so it should be ok. It is only the above it fails on, other XML seems fine. I don't know why it would be parsing to int for this.

Comment: Is the XML coming in from a network connection?

Comment: It is coming from a REST service, so yes. The response usually gets sent without issues - it is only with this one I have the problem.

Comment: Since the XML is good, the next thing that springs to mind is that you're getting an incomplete response from the REST service. Double check for that, maybe the response just isn't getting through all in one go.

Comment: I used fiddler to look at the raw data... seems the element in the line above might be the problem... wonder why it reported the line it did...??? will investigate and update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with a property, however, I was so busy looking at what the error message was saying, I missed it. The error message pointed to the wrong property!

Answer (score 2):

A VERY important note about XML error line and column numbers:
The XML declaration is not counted as a line, so position (0,0)
in your file is actually the second line, not the line with the declaration

EDIT: sorry, my point is that if the exception says there's something wrong at (23, 26), it's actually at (24,26).

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you can change type of the DiscountRate from `decimal` to `double` and see whether it works, it takes less memory and should be enough for such business entity like discount rate.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried that and it didn't make any difference. :( - +1 for the memory comment :)

Comment: There is only one other decimal property. I don't think this is the issue though, as other XML that comes back (as same object type) deserialises without a problem. This makes me think there are weird characters, but I can't see any. Also the inner exception stacktrace points to the tryparseint32 method being the issue as it should be trying to parse a double (or decimal)